# Error : Django 'ChoiceField' object has no attribute 'use_required_attribute'

Tags: python, django, forms

Here's my model (in models.py)

```
class Score(models.Model):

    ROUTINETYPE_CHOICE = (
        (0, 'R1'),
        (1, 'R2'),
        (2, 'F'),
    )

    routineType = models.IntegerField(choices=ROUTINETYPE_CHOICE)
    pointA = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    pointB = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    pointC = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)
```

And here's my Form (in forms.py)

```
class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        ROUTINETYPE_CHOICE = (
            (0, 'R1'),
            (1, 'R2'),
            (2, 'F'),
        )

        model = Score
        fields = ('routineType', 'pointA', 'pointB', 'pointC')

        widgets = {
            'routineType': forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROUTINETYPE_CHOICE),
            'pointA': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'xx,xx', 'value': '0'}),
            'pointB': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'xx,xx', 'value': '0'}),
            'pointC': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'xx,xx', 'value': '0'}),
        }
```

And my view is usual:

```
def score_create(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScoreForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/score/')

    else:
        form = ScoreForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'score_create.html', context)
```

When I try to display my form, django give me this error:

```
'ChoiceField' object has no attribute 'use_required_attribute'
```

The `use_required_attribute` is new in Django 1.10 and I've the possibility to set it to False. But it's on the Form level, it will say that my other fields are loosing the HTML `required` attribute too.

I've only three possibilities (with no "dummy" default option selected, like "choose…"), so my ChoiceField have always an option selected and then the HTML attribute "required" is fulfilled.

Someone know an another solution (other than set `use_required_attribute=False`) ?

Comment: A field is not a widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank Daniel. It was not a very detailed answer but, you'r right.

```
widgets = {
    'routineType': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-sm-2'}),
    'pointA': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-sm-2', 'placeholder': 'xx,xx', 'value': '0'}),
    'pointB': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-sm-2', 'placeholder': 'xx,xx', 'value': '0'}),
    'pointC': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control col-sm-2', 'placeholder': 'xx,xx', 'value': '0'}),
    }
```

And it's works !

Answer (score 1):

For anybody still wondering, there is an alternative to using `models.IntegerField` with `choices` argument and `forms.Select` inside `widgets`: `forms.ChoiceField` has to be moved from `Meta` class constructor to `ScoreForm` class constructor.

So the code will be along the lines of

```
class Score(models.Model):

    routineType = models.IntegerField()
    pointA = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    pointB = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    pointC = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3)


class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ROUTINETYPE_CHOICE = (
        (0, 'R1'),
        (1, 'R2'),
        (2, 'F'),
    )
    routineType = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ROUTINETYPE_CHOICE)

    class Meta:

        model = Score
        fields = ('routineType', 'pointA', 'pointB', 'pointC')

        widgets = {
            'pointA': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'xx,xx', 'value': '0'}),
            'pointB': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'xx,xx', 'value': '0'}),
            'pointC': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'xx,xx', 'value': '0'}),
        }
```

Comment: Thak you! Used this solution and it works fine...